Can macOS route some websites through Wi-Fi, while the rest use the Ethernet?
I am using macOS 15.1.1 in my office iMac and connected to the Internet via Ethernet and Wi-Fi. My office Ethernet blocks all VPN sites, while I can use my iPhone's personal hotspot to share Wi-Fi with the Mac.
I want to configure the Mac (or on browser-level / application-level) to route some websites (such as claude.ai / OpenAI websites) through Wi-Fi (VPN would be enabled in my iPhone), while the rest use the Ethernet. Is it possible?
The reason I don't want to use the personal hotspot all the time is that it would spend too much data via mobile network and it's too slow.

If your work ethernet blocks things you might want to look at the rules for doing this. It could well be a fireable offense to do this.

Yes
The straightforward way of doing this is to add an entry in your routing table as appropriate for each of the sites: route add -net 172.16.16.0/20 -interface en0, replacing the IP address and interface as appropriate for your desired sites and Wi-Fi/Ethernet. By nature, this is not domain-aware, which may make it somewhat annoying to configure for your specific use case if any of the traffic filtered traffic needs to go to a dynamic IP.
If you want to make it domain-aware, you could run a script which periodically updates your routes based on a DNS query. This script does not run automatically, but it's a good starting point; you could pretty trivially update this with a constant address or set of addresses, and set it to run at regular interval[s] with crontab.
